# Hilbert action's invariance under general coordinate changes

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vector-fields, diffeomorphism-invariance

In an article, when considering invariance of the Hilbert action under a general coordinate change this formula appears for how the metric changes

$$\delta{}g_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}\xi^{\rho}g_{\rho\nu}+\partial_{\nu}\xi^{\rho}g_{\rho\mu}+\xi^{\rho}\partial_{\rho}g_{\mu\nu}.$$

I have (maybe naively) tried using the tensor coordinate change formula considering $x^{\alpha}~\to~ x'^{\alpha}=x^{\alpha}+\xi^{\alpha}$ (formula I guessed,  it isn't specified in the article I am reading) but I don't get there.

So, how does this formula come up?

Comment: The best way to show that the Hilbert action is coordinate invariant is to note that its the Hodge dual of the Ricci scalar. Both the Hodge dual and the Ricci scalar are manifestly coordinate independent, isometry invariants, so the Hilbert action is too. If you don't know what the Hodge dual is, for a scalar it's the same as multiplying with the volume element.

Comment: It is nothing but the Lie derivative of $g$ with respect to the vector field $\xi$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Hints:

1. Recall that under a diffeomorphism $f$, the tensor transformation law tells us that the metric transforms as $g\to g_f$ where
   \begin{align}
   (g_f)_{\mu\nu}(f(x)) = g_{\alpha\beta}(x)\partial_\mu (f^{-1})^\alpha(f(x))\partial_\nu (f^{-1})^\beta(f(x))
   \end{align}
   which, sending $x\to f^{-1}(x)$ can be re-written as
   \begin{align}
     (g_f)_{\mu\nu}(x) = g_{\alpha\beta}(f^{-1}(x))\partial_\mu (f^{-1})^\alpha(x)\partial_\nu (f^{-1})^\beta(x). \tag{$\star$}
   \end{align}
2. Consider an infinitesimal diffeomorphism (physics speak for a smooth, one-parameter family of diffeomorphisms that starts at the identity)
   \begin{align}
     f(x)=x - \xi(x) + O(\xi^2)
   \end{align}
3. Notice that
   \begin{align}
     f^{-1}(x) = x+\xi(x) +O(\xi^2)
   \end{align}
4. Plug this into the right hand side of $(\star)$ and Taylor expand about $\xi=0$ to first order.
5. Recall that $\delta g = g_f - g + O(\xi^2)$, and compare to the expression you wrote down.

**Addendum. (2 April 2014)** Notice that the first transformation law I wrote down is a more mathematically explicit version of
\begin{align}
  (g')_{\mu\nu}(x') = g_{\alpha\beta}(x) \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x'^\mu}(x')\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial x'^\nu}(x')
\end{align}
since if we write $x' = f(x)$ then $x = f^{-1}(x')$ so in particular
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x'^\mu}(x') = \frac{\partial(f^{-1})^\alpha}{\partial x'^\mu}(f(x)) = \partial_\mu(f^{-1})^\alpha(f(x))
\end{align}
where in the last equality, I have simply suppressed the prime in the derivative notation; a derivative $\partial_0$ for example simply means "take the derivative with respect to the $0^\mathrm{th}$ argument of the function."  While we usually label the zeroth argument of $f^{-1}$ with the letter $x'^0$ because we are thinking of $f^{-1}$ as the transformation that maps us from the "primed" coordinates to the "unprimed" coordinates, but this is just a dummy label, and we don't strictly need it as long as the derivative tells us which argument of the function we are differentiating with respect to.

Comment: there's something that I don't see. You take a diffeomorphism $x\to{}x'=f(x)$ right? and then the backward relation is $x'\to{}x=f^{-1}(x')$. If I am not mistaken, the tensor should trans under the diffeo we mentioned as $g_{\mu\nu}(x)\to{}(g_f)_{\mu\nu}(x'=f(x))=g_{\alpha\beta}(x=f^{-1}(x'))\frac{\partial(f^{-1})^{\alpha}(x')}{\partial{}x'^{\mu}}\frac{\partial(f^{-1})^{\beta}(x')}{\partial{}x'^{\nu}}$ then why do you take derivatives of the $f$-s respect to the old coordinates? what am I missing?

Comment: (the first partial on the formula shows up bad but it doesn't let me edit it any more.)

Answer (score 0):

Write $$g^\mathfrak{ab} = x^\mathfrak{a}_\mu x^\mathfrak{b}_\nu g^{\mu\nu}.$$
Consider everything as a function of ${x'} = x + \xi$ and Taylor expand to first order.